# In Organum and Species Counterpoint why is one of the voices always in whole notes?

Tags: theory, harmony, melody, counterpoint, species-counterpoint

Edit: It was pointed out to me that counterpoint spawned from the Organum style of music. For more context, here’s information from two sources I just read. “Two  styles of Organum existed during this period (1) note-against-note and (2) florid  many-notes against long-held notes called melismas.” “Florid organum is A twelfth-century style of two-voice polyphony in which the lower voice sustains relatively long notes while the upper voice sings note groups of varying length above each note of the lower voice.”

***In Organum and Species Counterpoint, why is one of the voices always in whole notes, is it because that voice is to create the underlying harmony for the other voice? Are the long held notes pitch specific, as in are they always Tonic, 4th, Dominant and Octave?***

Comment: The real answer is probably because that’s how people wanted to write it. Same reason why most rock is in 4/4 time. It’s the style.

Comment: I remember the long notes in species counterpoint shortening to half notes partway through the species list.

Comment: When I think of organum I think of pieces like Perotin's "Sederunt," in which the long sustained notes are actually a pre-existing melodic line, expanded to enormous proportions. In this case the notes wouldn't be selected for their own sake; they're just the notes of the tune. Imagine writing a piece in which one voice was the opening line of "Twinkle twinkle little star," but with each syllable being held for 10-20 measures.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not equate organum to species counterpoint.

Organum is from around 1200, but Fux's *Gradus ad Parnassum* is from 1725. They are totally different time periods and not the same style. Additional, organum was an actual musical style, whereas species counterpoint was a teaching method.

In organum you can think of the long notes like drones or pedal tones. It was a way to "thicken" the sound, just like parallel organum thickened the sound.

In species counterpoint the whole notes are essentially a way to simplify rhythm so the student can focus on relative motion between voices.

Also, keep in mind those species counterpoint lines in whole notes are supposed to exhibit good melodic shape and independence from the other voices, which is different from organum pedal tones and parallel voices. The voices in organum either work as pedals, not melodies, or duplicate parts in parallel, which does not achieve melodic independence.

Answer (score 1):

Pieces counterpoint is a drill, not sa compositional tool. Using whole notes is a convention. It is based on the technique used for centuries of laying out a Chant melody in long notes and adding more voices. Fux simplified the ideas and made them into a teaching method.

Comment: Interesting. I have seen some music from those centuries. That use breve, longa, & maxima notes. This link (https://louis.pressbooks.pub/exploringarts/chapter/introduction-to-music/) says, “Around the late 12th century, a particular style of organum developed in the Cathedral of Notre Dame in Paris. This style involved holding out the notes of a Gregorian chant while a very active new melody was sung above it.“ So, my main questions are still sort of the same. But now also pertaining to “organum”.

Comment: @Lecifer - And I'm betting that we use whole notes instead of anything longer because breves are already rare and exotic in modern sheet music and longa and maxima notes are pretty much nonexistent there.

Comment: @Lecifer - I suspect we don't use half notes instead for low species because the melismas on top would start demanding some *really* short notes. My transcription of Meta Knight's most often used boss theme is already hard enough to read in 5/4 time with 16th-note quintuplets - my transcription of a remix of another video game theme named "Zaghnol Comes" is hell to read in 6/8 time with **64th notes**. Yes, I sometimes regret not putting that transcription in 6/4 time instead, especially since my public version has ridiculously many 32nd notes.